# Disconnected graph when concatenating two models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Trying to build a new model based on part of pre-trained model,

Here's some cleaned out code.

Let's imagine we got model1 trained, and want to add some layers defined in model2:

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential

model1 = Sequential([
    Conv2D(2, (3,3), padding='same', input_shape=(6,6,1)),
    Activation('relu')
])
model2 = Sequential([
    Conv2D(3, (3,3), padding='same', input_shape=(6,6,2)),
    Activation('softmax')
])

model_merge = Model(inputs=model1.input, 
                    outputs=Activation('softmax')(model2(model1.get_layer('conv2d').output)))
```

It looks a bit messy, but I want to demonstrate it's not disconnected by adding a softmax activation here.

summary of model1:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 6, 6, 2)           20        
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 6, 6, 2)           0         
=================================================================
Total params: 20
Trainable params: 20
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

summary of model2:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 6, 6, 3)           57        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 6, 6, 3)           0         
=================================================================
Total params: 57
Trainable params: 57
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________
```

And summary of model_merge:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_input (InputLayer)    (None, 6, 6, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 6, 6, 2)           20        
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_2 (Sequential)    (None, 6, 6, 3)           57        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 6, 6, 3)           0         
=================================================================
Total params: 77
Trainable params: 77
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Let's prove this merged model is not disconnected:

```
layers = [layer.output for layer in model_merge.layers]
test1 = Model(inputs=model_merge.input, outputs=layers[-1])
```

Everything works just fine.

test1's summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_input (InputLayer)    (None, 6, 6, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 6, 6, 2)           20        
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_2 (Sequential)    (None, 6, 6, 3)           57        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 6, 6, 3)           0         
=================================================================
Total params: 77
Trainable params: 77
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here's the tragedy:

```
test2 = Model(inputs=model_merge.input, outputs=layers[-2])
```

The most important feed back:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("conv2d_2_input:0", shape=(?, 6, 6, 2), dtype=float32) at layer "conv2d_2_input". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

full feedback:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-946b325081c1> in <module>
----> 1 test = Model(inputs=model_merge.input, outputs=layers[-2])

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    119 
    120   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 121     super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    122     # Create a cache for iterator get_next op.
    123     self._iterator_get_next = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     79         'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
     80       # Graph network
---> 81       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
     82     else:
     83       # Subclassed network

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    440     self._setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    441     try:
--> 442       method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    443     finally:
    444       self._setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name)
    219     # Keep track of the network's nodes and layers.
    220     nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, layers_by_depth = _map_graph_network(
--> 221         self.inputs, self.outputs)
    222     self._network_nodes = nodes
    223     self._nodes_by_depth = nodes_by_depth

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
   1850                              'The following previous layers '
   1851                              'were accessed without issue: ' +
-> 1852                              str(layers_with_complete_input))
   1853         for x in node.output_tensors:
   1854           computable_tensors.append(x)

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("conv2d_2_input:0", shape=(?, 6, 6, 2), dtype=float32) at layer "conv2d_2_input". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

It's really driving me crazy,

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layer you are trying to use as output has two output nodes. The first connects the input of `model2` to the output of the `model2`. The second output node connects the output of the `model1` and the first layer of `model2`. By default, the layer output returns only the first output node. So what is happening is you are tying to connect the input of the `model_merge`(input of `model1`) with the first output node.

To following code shows this. Individual output nodes of the layer can be accessed using the `get_output_at()` method of the layer.

```py
layer_output = model_merge.layers[-2].output # The first output node
layer_output_1 = model_merge.layers[-2].get_output_at(0) # The first output node
layer_output_2 = model_merge.layers[-2].get_output_at(1) # The second output node
```

Now the following two codes throws error because the graph is disconnected.

```py
test2 = Model(inputs=model_merge.input, outputs=layer_output)
```

and

```py
test2 = Model(inputs=model_merge.input, outputs=layer_output_1)
```

But the code below doesnot throw error, because the graph is connected.

```py
test2 = Model(inputs=model_merge.input, outputs=layer_output_2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what's happening is: I defined this layer first time in model 2 so it generated the first output node connecting the input and output of model2 , then I created model_merge so it generated second output node connecting the output of model 1 and the output of model2, right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening.